# New WCF web service returns 401 in one environment

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-401

We recently deployed a WCF web service to our prod environment.  Attempts to call it or even access the WSDL from a browser return a 401.  Where would this authentication be happening?

This service sits in its own virtual application under a website with a dozen other similar services.  These do not exhibit the same symptoms.  Similarly, this did not occur on any of three pre-prod environments.

I've looked through IIS settings on the virtual app and the application pool but nothing stands out to me.  The only discrepancy I see between the UAT and Production configs is the prod one targets 4.6.1 instead of 4.6.2.

Web.config from prod:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this one site would be bouncing connections as unauthorized--even when just browsing to hit the wsdl?

**UPDATE**
After thinking and checking [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2005/07/15/howto-diagnose-401-x-http-errors-on-iis/), I found the sub-status code being
returned was 3, indicating permissions on the folder.  Adding everyone (temporarily) fixed the issue.  This still leaves trying to track down why a virtual app under the same site as many others, using the same account to run the app pool as all other app pools experienced this issue.

Comment: Can you confirm you have 'Anonymous Authentication' turned on in IIS?

Comment: @Zeus82 - Thanks.  It is.

Comment: Do you know if the app was compiled with 4.6.2?  Could you try compiling it with 4.6.1 and try for a moment?  Any messages in your NT Event log?

Comment: @tgolisch - Thanks.  It was actually built under 4.7.1.  I changed the config to reference 4.6.2 (as in lower environments) but it had no effect.

Comment: If you copy/pasted the app's folder (into a parent folder), it might not automatically inherit permissions from the parent (virtual app).

Comment: In my opinion, there are some problems in deploying the project. Where do you deploy the project? Don’t set up the virtual directory to Desktop folder, configure the directory to C/D partition. Do you have enabled the WCF feature in IIS and which version of IIS hosting the service you use?

Comment: We have checked permissions and forced child folders and files to inherit the parent settings.

Comment: It is deployed to C:\inetpub\MyServices\Service2 on Win2012R2/IIS 8.0 server.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how do you configure during the deploy/publish process. On my side, I have made a simple demo, it works normally.I would like that you could share more details about your project.
**Server(configuration)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpsBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
      </binding>
    </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Server(interface/class).**

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
}
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

My server environment (10.157.13.70) is win10, IIS10. virtual path is C:\Test.
Here is what I have done in IIS.
Add the https binding and development certificate.
[image]
Besides, I have the Anonymous Authentication enable in IIS authentication module(default settings).
**WCF feature.**
[image]
Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.